# Bundle on webforms js files not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

Why does it not recognize the functions? I have included them in order like in the normal references style

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AdminlteJs").Include(
        "~/AdminLTE/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "~/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
        "~/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
        "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"
        ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/PluginsJs").Include(
        "~/Plugins/js/animsition.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/js/iziModal.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/js/iziToast.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/js/noty.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/FontAwesome/js/all.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/jQueryValidation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "~/Plugins/jQueryFileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ScriptsJs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/LoginForm/js/PageAnimation.js",
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/MenuSelection.js",
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/Notification.js",
        "~/Scripts/MasterPage/PageTransition.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/DataTables.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/FileUpload.js",
        "~/Scripts/Pages/Validaion.js"));

}
```

Bundle.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/bundles/AdminLte/css">
    <include path="~/AdminLTE/dist/js/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <include path="~/AdminLTE/dist/css/adminlte.min.css" />
    <include path="~/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" />
  </styleBundle>

  <styleBundle path="~/bundles/Plugins/css">
    <include path="~/Plugins/css/minified/animsition.min.css" />
    <include path="~/Plugins/css/minified/iziModal.min.css" />
    <include path="~/Plugins/css/minified/iziToast.min.css" />
    <include path="~/Plugins/css/noty.css" />
    <include path="~/Plugins/FontAwesome/css/all.min.css" />
  </styleBundle>

  <styleBundle path="~/bundles/Styles/css">
    <include path="~/Styles/LoginForm/css/style.css" />
    <include path="~/Styles/MasterPages/Layout.css" />
    <include path="~/Styles/MasterPages/Loader.css" />
    <include path="~/Styles/MasterPages/PageTransition.css" />
  </styleBundle>

</bundles>
```

And on masterpage

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/AdminLte/css") %>
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/Plugins/css") %>
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/Styles/css") %>

    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AdminLteJs") %>
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/PluginsJs") %>d
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ScriptsJs") %>    

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

the bundle.config for the css files is working, but for JS from the bundleconfig.cs not, many functions not defined errors on console...

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that my folder structure was just a mess, I tried to install plugins from nuget manager to see where it placed js and css files and just added them to bundle from those folders because some plugins have some references to fonts or images etc...

Also, place script render files on header solves the problem of pages not finding functions on master page.